# Generic Form Data in Scout Eclips

Tags: generics, form-data, eclipse-scout

I would like to know how to set generic form data on class.

I have class like this :

```
@FormData(value = AbstractMoreSmartFieldFormData.class, sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.CREATE,
defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
public class AbstractMoreSmartField<T> extends AbstractSmartField<T> implements IMoreField {

  public Boolean isMore;

  @FormData
  public Boolean getIsMore() {
    return this.isMore;
  }

  @FormData
  public void setIsMore(Boolean isMore) {
     this.isMore = isMore;
  }
...
```

But it create form data like this :

```
public class AbstractMoreSmartFieldFormData extends AbstractValueFieldData<Object> {
```

and does not take `T` from creating class in to account. 
How to fix this?

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out

You change `sdkCommand` to `USE` like :

```
@FormData(value = AbstractMoreSmartFieldFormData.class, sdkCommand = FormData.SdkCommand.USE,
defaultSubtypeSdkCommand = FormData.DefaultSubtypeSdkCommand.CREATE)
```

Then you can change `AbstractMoreSmartFieldFormData` and will not be overwritten when form data is update.

so change form data to

```
public class AbstractMoreSmartFieldFormData<T> extends AbstractValueFieldData<T>
```